# copping Sharepoint environment from one farm to another

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-2013

i am trying to migrating (copping actually) an intranet from one environment to another with new SharePoint farm, i am willing to perform content database restore approach, 
my questions are:
-we have two free apps installed in the current environment and i am wondering whether it would be migrated or i would have to re install it on the new environment.
-also i would like to know the best way to configure the new users permissions.

the sharepoint version is 2013.

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

you would have to reinstall the apps.
when you migrate using database restore, the users are also migrated.